# Angular service null?

Tags: angular

I have created a project in angular 7, and I have copied some code from former angular projects. First I make a very simple service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { HttpClient,HttpErrorResponse} from  '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private  httpClient:  HttpClient) { 

  }

  getValues():Observable<string[]>{
    var url = `${environment.apiUrl}/api/values`;
    return  this.httpClient.get<string[]>(url);    
  }

  getTest():Observable<string[]>{
    var url = `${environment.apiUrl}/api/test`;
    return  this.httpClient.get<string[]>(url);    
  }
}
```

Then I just simply call it from a component:

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../api.service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'fleet.component.html'
})
export class FleetComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private  apiService:  ApiService) {}  

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.apiService.getValues()
    .subscribe(
      result => {
        // Handle result
        console.log(result)
      },
      error => {
        alert(error);
      },
      () => {
        // 'onCompleted' callback.
        // No errors, route to new page here
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Hovever this.apiService is null? Am i missing something here? I can see I don't have any imports or declarations in my old project.

All help is appreciated

Error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HttpClient]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HttpClient]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
>   Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HttpClient]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HttpClient]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
>       at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:8896)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
>       at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8982)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
>       at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8982)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:21218)
>       at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:21907)
>       at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:1774)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
>       at zone.js:892
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Where does the `url` variable come from in the service?

Comment: I dont think url matters, the function is never called because the apiService object is null:(

Comment: Did you import the httpModule on app.module.ts ?

Comment: Based on the error message, you may have forgotten to add the `HttpClientModule` to the application module.

Comment: That was exactly what I had :D Thanks. Can you leave an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { NgModule }         from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // import HttpClientModule after BrowserModule.
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```